# transferring data from table to table after deleting them

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have a table, let's assume it's like that :

```
id    name      salary
1     mohamed   2500
2     ahmed     1800
3     micheal   3400
```

I want to transfer all this data to another table

```
log_id   id    name   salary
```

where log_id is an auto_increment key.

what I tried is

```
select * into table_2 from dbo.table1
delete from dbo.table1 where 1=1
```

is that right? or there's a better query so I can make it in one line or better performance?

Thanks.

Comment: No WHERE clause needed. Depending on your needs, TRUNCATE TABLE may be a suitable way to empty the first table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,name,salary)
SELECT id,name,salary
FROM dbo.table1
```

When you doing INSERT operation using SELECT it is best practice to explicitly mention the column names in `INSERT INTO` and `SELECT` statement, just to make sure right data lands in the right columns.

Once you have transfered the data then you can use `Delete` or `Truncate` commands to delete the data in table1. keeping in mind you can limit the number or rows being deleted using delete command with a `WHERE` clause.

If you want to delete all the records in table1 just use `Truncate` command. which is much faster and logs fewer logs and you cannot use WHERE Cluase with truncate. It also resets the Identity column in you table.

Comment: Delete command places rollback records in transaction log depending upon recovery model (FULL causes a lot of logging).  Truncate is faster, less logging.  If DELETE action is > 50% of records, maybe SELECT INTO temp table, drop original table.  Rename temp as original.  Add back other objects as such as indexes.  This option might be less over head than a DELETE of 3.0 M records from a 3.5 M record table.

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA thanks for the information, a very good point too :) +1

Comment: Tx - I have been down the road in which a delete of X Million rows took for ever.  (:)->-<

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA well they say `“Smart people learn from their mistakes. But the real sharp ones learn from the mistakes of others.”`, and I have just learnt something new from your mistake/experience. :D

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your requirements.  Two ways come to mind.

```
--
-- 1 - Create new table on the fly
--

-- Remove existing
if object_id('table2') > 0
drop table2;
go

-- Create new table (must have rights)
select * into table2 from table1;
go


--
-- 2 - Load existing table
--

-- Remove data
truncate table table2;
go

-- Add data
insert into table2 
select * from table1;
go
```

Lets talk about pros/cons of both solutions.

Solution 1 creates a table on the fly.  The person executing the code has to have rights to CREATE TABLE.  It might save you transaction log space.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx

Under the simple recovery model or bulk-logged recovery model, bulk operations are minimally logged. With minimal logging, using the SELECT… INTO statement can be more efficient than creating a table and then populating the table with an INSERT statement.

Solution 2 adds data to an existing table.  The user only needs to have INSERT rights.
Having the table in existence ahead of time allows you to do things like build the table on a filegroup and pre-allocate the file size.

This solution might run faster if existing space did not exist in the data file for solution 1.  However, you will be incurring log space if you use a full recovery model.